# LSP with pyright and poetry

Tags: python, lsp

I want LSP to allow me to use pyright with peotry projects. The problem is, that the `venv` of a poetry project is kind of arbitrary and can change. So I can not configure it in the pyright config file.

Can LSP be configured to "autodetect" this environment and set it for pyright when I open a project?

Comment: "Autodetect"? I can't even configure pyright to use venv _manually_.

Comment: I am not very sure, what is LSP, maybe lightest supersymmetric particle? :-) Probably you wanted to ask it on the stackoverflow.com , but not sure. Note, your question will be likely closed also there, because probably not even they know, what is LSP. Note, technically would be easy to move your question there, but... but.... but... there are some major structural problems on this site network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyright correctly recognizes python on your PATH. So if you activate a virtual environment in a shell and open neovim there, everything should work as expected.

Run the following command in neovim

```
!which python
```

or

```
echo $PATH
```

to see whether the virtualenv python is detected in neovim.

Comment: `!which python` has nothing to do with neovim, though. It's a shell command.

Comment: Yes, it is a shell command but the `$PATH` environment variable will be propagated to the subshell command executed in neovim. So it can tell which python will be picked by pyright (it chooses one as per `$PATH`) -- unless you configured pyright to use a different python interpreter.